# How to copy contents from One Azure web apps to another web in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

There are two Web apps(*WebSite1, WebSite2*) hosted in Azure. It is observed that *WebSite1* is working fine for me. So we want whatever contents are there in WebSite1, those contents needs to be copied to Website2.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Simplest and straight forward is to use FTP to download from one and upload to another.    As best practice, the source of content (truth) should be in some repository so you can deploy to any future website and backup in case you accidentally delete the site.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you could use the FTP e.g [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org) to download the files in the `wwwroot` of your web app1 and upload to the web app2.

Or if you don't mind to create a new web app2, you can use the [Azure App Service App Cloning Using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning) feature, note the [current restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#current-restrictions). To clone the app, you can also do that in the azure portal -> your web app1 -> `Clone App`.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.)